# Is there a way to have multiple dialog boxes with Twitter-Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for everything and it's great but am at the point where I need multiple dialog boxes on the screen. I have not been able to find in the documentation how to do this so I'm assuming it is not something that is included.

I'm looking for something similar to jQuery-UI dialog boxes (NOT modals)

Is there a way to achieve this with Twitter Bootstrap without writing a new piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not problem in doing so. I've a project where it is working fine. There is one 'glitch' the backdrop is stacked so the backdrop (if you use it) of the first dialog is leading and for every dialog one gets stacked on top of it. The dialog you opened first is not greyed out. So probable you want to load you dialog with .modal("show", {backdrop: false}) after the first one and if possible you want your dialogs to be of the same size or bigger then the previously opened dialogs to circumvent the problem.

In our case it's an internal application, so this is not a big issue. But for a public website I could imagine this is a showstopper.